# Order a list of string elements based on length first and then sort it based on alphabetical order for elements with matching length

Tags: python, pandas

Good day !!

Request your help with a problem that I am facing currently. I have a list named username as given below:

username = ['Paul',   'Polish',   'poloski',   'melind', 'Melinda', 'MeRind','arabic','arabia']

a) I would like to sort this list based on the descending order of length / sorted
b) For elements whose lengths are the same, I would like to sort them considering each letter that makes up the element just as how it would appear in a dictionary (for example 'arabia' before 'arabic')

To make it clearer, my objective is to create the final modified list to appear  something like:

['Melinda','poloski','arabia','arabic','melind','MeRind','Polish','Paul')

Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
username.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item), item.lower()), reverse=False)                                                                                                           

In [3715]: username                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[3715]: 
['Melinda',
 'poloski',
 'arabia',
 'arabic',
 'melind',
 'MeRind',
 'Polish',
 'Paul']
```

You can do this in a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(username).apply(lambda x: list((sorted(x, key=lambda item: (-len(item), item.lower())))))                                                                              

         0
0  Melinda
1  poloski
2   arabia
3   arabic
4   melind
5   MeRind
6   Polish
7     Paul
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) can take a function that returns a tuple for the key, the first element of each tuple will be used for sorting and then on a conflict the second and so on.

To sort by first length and then alphabetically (ignoring case)

```
sorted(username, key=lambda u: (len(u), u.lower()))
```